# Spitting out the URL of the entry

Tags: variable, request

Bear with me.

Shortly changing a site to run over https vs http - the issue is though that we need to maintain the Facebook open graph share data.

Facebook makes distinction between https and http. The way to maintain this is just to add `<meta property="og:url" content="//www.myurl.com/segment/segment" />`

Is there a variable I can access that would output the current URL without the protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build it up using a couple of the request variables:

```
{{ craft.request.serverName ~'/'~ craft.request.getSegments | join('/') }}
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me to answering my own question :D

Comment: Haha, sorry. I'm not normally quick enough to get a right answer in :)

Comment: That'll teach me to post and then start speaking to a colleague ;)